# Kripke models of $HA$

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, peano-arithmetic, constructive-mathematics, bounded-arithmetic

Let $K$ be a kripke model and $k$ be one of its node, then $\mathcal{M}_k$ is classical structure of $k$.

> What is the strongest theory of arithmetic like $T$ such that for
>   every kripke  model $K\Vdash HA$ and for every nodes of it like $k$,
>   $\mathcal{M}_k\models T$?.

It is not hard to see that $T\vdash I\Delta_0$, because $HA$ proves least number principle for $\Delta_0$ formulas.

I found two paper that partially answered this question:

[Finite Kripke models of HA are locally PA](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093636765)

[Every Rooted Narrow Tree Kripke Model of HA is Locally PA](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-3870(200204)48:3%3C391::AID-MALQ391%3E3.0.CO;2-T/abstract)

I want to know is there any other results on this question?
Also can $T$ be a stronger theory than $I\Delta_0$ like $I\Sigma_1$?

Comment: The abstract of the first paper you mention (by van Dalen et al.) states that $T$ includes at least $I\Delta_1$; this seems to follow from the results in section 4 of the paper (by the way,  $I\Delta_1$ is known to be equivalent to $B\Sigma_1$ in the presence $I\Delta_0$ + "exponentiation is a total function").

Comment: @AliEnayat: Thank you for your comment. By " $I\Delta_1$ is known to be equivalent to $B\Sigma_1$ in the presence $I\Delta_0+EXP$ " you mean $$I\Delta_0+EXP\vdash B\Sigma_1 \equiv I\Delta_1$$?

Comment: Yes, for more detail see Slaman's 2004 paper available at: http://www.ams.org.ezproxy.ub.gu.se/journals/proc/2004-132-08/S0002-9939-04-07294-6/S0002-9939-04-07294-6.pdf